# How can I filter a column by multiples of a number?

Tags: r, filter

I have a Strava dataset with 5 columns: edge_id, year, day, hour, commute_count.
The day field is a numeric field which ranges between 1 and 365. However, because the count happens hourly and per edge (street), days are repeated (see image for clarity).
I  need to remove every record for saturday - sundays from the table. I thought I could filter out the multiples of 6 and 7 from the "day" column but I can't figure out how. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data. The gold standard for providing data is using `dput(head(NameOfYourData))`, *editing* your question and putting the `structure()` output into the question.

Comment: You could try `df[df$day %% 7 != c(0,6)]`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on how to post data. Apologies for that, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the subset function and a condition based on modulo:
`day %% 6` equals 0 if day is a multiple of 6.
Therefore, the condition day%%6 !=0 keep only values that are not multiple of 6.

```
new.df = subset(df, day%%6 !=0  & day%%7 != 0)
```